# Exterior Algebra and linearly independent vectors

Tags: abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Suppose that $v_1,\cdots,v_r$ are linearly independent vectors in some vector space $V$. I want to try and show that for any $w \in \bigwedge^p(V)$ that
$$
w = \sum_{i=1}^{r} v_i \wedge \psi_i
$$
for some $\psi_i \in \bigwedge^{p-1}(V)$ if and only if
$$
v_1\wedge v_2\wedge \cdots \wedge v_r\wedge w = 0.
$$

The forward direction is trivial by writing $w$ as the sum and extending the wedge product linearly. It's the second implication that's giving me some trouble.

If we assume that $v_1\wedge v_2\wedge \cdots \wedge v_r\wedge w = 0$, then I want to conclude that I can write $w$ in the appropriate form by examining well-chosen alternating, multi-linear forms from $V^{p+r}$ into some vector space so that I can use the universal property of $\bigwedge^{p+r}(V)$, and evaluate the induced map at $v_1\wedge v_2\wedge \cdots \wedge v_r\wedge w$ and get $0$.

The problem I'm having is that $w$ is not necessarily an elementary wedge product, so I don't have a canonical way of thinking of it as an element of $V^p$.
Any ideas for this backward direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the result that if $v_1, \dots v_n$ are a basis of $V$ then their wedge products are a basis of $\wedge^k(V)$? That's enough to conclude here (by extending $v_i$ to a basis and then computing in the wedge product basis).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I am familiar with that result, I'll see if playing around with the details makes it clearer.

Comment: To re-emphasize, extending to a basis is the right starting point 95% of the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{e_1,\ldots, e_k\}$ be a basis of $V$ such that $v_i=e_i$ for $1\le i\le r$. $w\in \bigwedge^p(V) \implies$

$$w = \sum_{\alpha\in P}f_{\alpha}e_{\alpha_1}\wedge\ldots \wedge e_{\alpha_s}$$
Where $P = \{(i_1,\ldots, i_s) \mid 1 \le  i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_s \le k, s\leq p\}$ and I will use $|\alpha|$ to denote the number of elements in the tuple. Clearly
$$v_1\wedge \cdots \wedge v_r =  e_{1}\wedge\cdots \wedge e_{r}$$
So
\begin{align*}
&v_1\wedge  \cdots \wedge v_r\wedge w = 0\\ 
\implies&  e_{1}\wedge\cdots \wedge e_{r}\wedge  \sum_{\alpha\in P}f_{\alpha}e_{\alpha_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge e_{\alpha_s} = 0\\
\implies& \forall \alpha\in P, f_\alpha \neq 0 \implies \exists l_\alpha \leq |\alpha|, \alpha_{l_\alpha} \leq r \text{ (Let $l_\alpha$ denote the least such value)}\\
\implies& w = \sum_{\alpha\in P, f_\alpha \neq0}f_{\alpha}e_{\alpha_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge e_{\alpha_m}\wedge e_{l_\alpha}\wedge e_{\alpha_n}\wedge \cdots \wedge e_{\alpha_s} \space\space(\alpha_m<l_\alpha<\alpha_n)\\
\implies& w = \sum_{\alpha\in P, f_\alpha \neq0}f_{\alpha}(-1)^m e_{l_\alpha}\wedge e_{\alpha_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge e_{\alpha_m}\wedge e_{\alpha_n}\wedge \cdots \wedge e_{\alpha_s} \space\space(\alpha_m<l_\alpha<\alpha_n)\\
\implies& w = \sum_{i=1}^rv_{i}\wedge\sum_{\alpha\in P, f_\alpha \neq0,l_\alpha = i}f_{\alpha}(-1)^m\wedge e_{\alpha_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge e_{\alpha_m}\wedge  e_{\alpha_n}\wedge \cdots \wedge e_{\alpha_s} \space\space(\alpha_m<l_\alpha<\alpha_n)
\end{align*}
Might have made a mistake somewhere but the idea should be clear. If you have a notation that you suggest I use for clarity, please feel free to comment!

Comment: In your argument you need to extend $\{ v_1, \dots v_k \}$ to a basis of $V$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I think it should be correct now @QiaochuYuan

Comment: I don't think I quite follow your second implication. You seem to be saying that if $e_1\wedge\cdots\wedge e_r \wedge \sum_{\alpha\in P} f_\alpha e_{\alpha_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{\alpha_s} = 0$ then we must have that each of the summands in $\sum_{\alpha \in P} f_\alpha(e_1\wedge \cdots\wedge e_r\wedge e_{\alpha_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge e_{\alpha_s})$ must be zero. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes! This is true since each of the summands are linearly independent. I.E if one of the $(e_1\wedge \cdots\wedge e_r\wedge e_{\alpha_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge e_{\alpha_s})$ is non zero, there is not some other one which potentially cancels with it. @MathManiac5772

Comment: Might be helpful to see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53558/bases-for-exterior-powers) post on a basis for the exterior algebra or maybe browse through the posts in the "Related" tab on the right side of this page. @MathManiac5772

Comment: @RyanK That's a perfect explanation. Thank you so much.